# If I sent a message through a single-circuit telegraph across a copper wire to the Andromeda galaxy, will my message be received instantaneously?

Tags: current, circuit-analysis

I recently learned that electric current flows like a bicycle chain where all the electrons push each other at the same time. This got me thinking. Would this have the same effect at an astronomical scale where one could send a message by telegraph 2.5 million light years away with no delay?

[image]

*For extra credit, could general relativity play a part?*

Comment: You learned wrong.

Comment: Voting to close this as it has nothing to do with electronics design in the scope of how we understand it in the local solar system and on this web site.

Comment: perhaps mechanical engineering?  I'd like to find out how the wire got there  in the first place without being stretched to pieces. I mean, the differential velocity alone is about 300 Km/s !!!

Comment: The 'bicycle chain' model was appropriate in your other question, to demonstrate the effect of Kirchoff's circuit laws, that no charge builds up at a node. However it's still a simple model, and inaccurate to describe transmission over long distances, as it lacks the wave equation element.

Comment: Voting to close as off-topic. No, absolutely nothing happens "instantaneously."* *c*, the speed of light, is the *speed of causality.* Meaning that *c* is the fastest anything without mass may propagate, in this galaxy or any other. Seeing that the distance is 2.5M light-years, and electricity flows through a wire slower than as a radio wave, it would take >2.5M years to travel that distance.  *Ignoring quantum mechanics.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, electromagnetic waves propagate at the speed of light. But the speed of light in a copper conductor is not the same as the speed of light in a vacuum: c depends on electric field permeability and magnetic field permitivity. As a practical matter, an electrical signal propagates at a rate of about 1ns per 20cm to 30cm, depending on how the conductor and surrounding dielectric are constructed.

You are right that current does flow "like a bicycle chain" rather than like a water pipe; I think the water pipe metaphor is lacking because it does not account for the need for a return current. Nothing else really behaves quite like electricity, so any metaphor is only a rough approximation.

However if you examine the "bicycle chain" metaphor more closely, there really is a pressure wave that propagates through the chain. One side is pushing and the other side is pulling. In a real bicycle chain, this metaphor breaks down because a chain can only pull, it can't push. But electricity has both positive and negative charges. In semiconductor electronics, we sometimes speak of "holes" propagating through the cloud of valence electrons, effectively a "hole" is a place where there's fewer electrons. And these "holes" propagate through the cloud just as though they were positively charged carriers. So in effect there is both a current of negatively charged electrons flowing one direction, and a virtual current of positively charged "holes" flowing the opposite direction.

And yes, at astronomical scales it is essential to consider relativistic effects. It's doubtful that one could actually string a pair of wires between two galaxies, let alone between say the earth and the moon. However it is practical to send a radio signal or a pulse of light. Mars is 10-20 light-minutes away, that's how long it takes a radio control signal to propagate between a terrestrial station and a remote controlled rover.

Comment: *c* (the speed of light in a vacuum) does not depend on the permeability and permitivity of any material. It is always  299792458 m/s. However, electromagnetic signals do not propagate at *c* when passing through materials.

Answer (score 2):

Even if it was feasible to string a wire from Earth to the Andromeda galaxy, which it is not, the signal along a wire travels at less than the speed of light. So there is no "instantaneous" transmission as we understand physics today.

By the way you could not build a copper wire strong enough that would be able to support itself getting up out of the earth's gravity well.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers, while essentially correct, miss the mark slightly with regard to the reason. It is not necessary to refer to permittivity and permeabililty to explain the finite propagation speed. After all, we're talking about empty space and potentially superconducting wires here.

The fact is that electrons "push" each other via their electric fields, changes in which propagate at the speed of light in a vacuum (or slightly slower inside other materials). In other words, if you shift an electron from one place to another, an electron 1 foot away won't "feel" the effects of it until 1 nanosecond later.

Light propagates at the speed of light, and no other effect, such as the flow of current, can propagate any faster than that. Yes, that is a direct result of special relativity.

Another reason that the signal propagates at a fixed speed is that all conductors of nonzero size have inductance and capacitance. The two wires connecting the two galaxies interact with each other as well as the universe at large. We call this relationship a "transmission line", and when you change conditions at one end of the line (e.g., closing a telegraph key), it takes a finite amount of time for the effects to propagate a particular distance down the line. It takes time to build up the current in the inductance and to charge up the capacitance with voltage.

This [velocity factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity_factor) is given by the equation

$$VF = \frac{1}{c \sqrt{LC}}$$

The specific values of inductance and capacitance do depend on the permittivity and permeability of free space, and they would be different if the space around the wires was anything other than a vacuum, but you get a finite speed of propagation in any case.

Answer (score 1):

No.  The signal will travel somewhat slower than the speed of light in vacuum.  And it will be attenuated to the point of indistinguishability for cables longer than a few hundred km.